# python Error: import module not found

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python API on my EC2,
 I have been developing the application on my Mac using PyCharm and I can compile it because I have the main directory as "root for the modules"
when trying to run my code off from any terminal, I am getting this error.

```
File "runserver.py", line 2, in <module>
from app import app
File "path to the __init__.py file", line 12,    in <module>
import call.authien
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'call'
```

here is my file structure:

```
API
|-- runserver.py
`-- app
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- call
  |-- __init__.py
  |   `-- authien.py
 |-- routes
 |-- models
```

the import modules are inside the `app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path='')
app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

import call.authien

import routes.users
import routes.hours
import routes.pref
```

Comment: It looks like `call` is nested under `app`, so you probably want something like `from .call import authien`.  You didn't say which version of Python you're using, but this is probably an absolute import versus relative import problem (Python 3 did away with implicit relative imports).  Be careful if you're developing in Python 2 and deploying to Python 3.  There are some important differences between the two versions.

Comment: I am using python 2. and when adding "from . import call.authien" I am getting a syntax error...

Comment: I typed it in wrong at first... look at my comment again (I corrected it immediately afterwards).  Try `from .call import authien`.

Comment: There might be a different issue too... it looks like `call/__init__.py` might be a directory, not a file.